# Developpement Android: Sending sms to a group of person

Tags: android, sms

(sorry for my bad english, i'm french...)

I have to send sms to multiple people.
For the moment, what i do is that:

```
for (String num : numbers)
    manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(num, null, parts, null, null);
```

And I've few problems:

1)First, There is a limitation that limits the number of sms i can send (100 i think), before my phone asks me to validate each message before to send it...

2)All sms are not sent (it is marked "Impossible sending" when i look this message from an other application)

3)There is one thread created for each person in the group, which is painfull...

Can somebody help me, please ? Thank you :)